# How to create a UIViewController with FreeForm by code ?. NOT USING STORYBOARD

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with creating UIViewController with Freeform option with code.
Note: I don't use storyboard for this UIViewController.

Comment: Freeform is an option for visualizing, you can't set it from code because there is not such an idea as Freeform at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Usually, create `UIView` in viewController

```
let view2 = UIView()
view2.backgroundColor = .red
self.view.addSubview(view2)

view2.topAnchor.constraint(view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
view2.leftAnchor.constraint(view.leftAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
view2.bottomAnchor.constraint(view.bottomAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
view2.rightAnchor.constraint(view.rightAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
```

And if you mean creating `viewController` and push to it, you need to create a new file with the subclass of `UIViewController` then use this code to navigate

```
self.navigationViewController?.pushViewController(rootViewController: NewFileViewController())
```